Manually choosing density of points for PlotPoints option
I'm using
ParametricPlot[(*some function*),{(*plot variable and some range*)},PlotPoints->{variable}]

and I was wondering if there was a way to set the density of where these plotpoints are with respect to the output or with respect to the plotting variable. I know I can improve the look of my graphs significantly without more computation time if I can do so, I just can't find anything in the documentation. I thought MeshFunction would do it, but realized I was wrong.

There are 2 relevant options here: PlotPoints and MaxRecursion. PlotPoints determines the initial number of points and MaxRecursion determines how often the plot attempts to refine parts of the plot that don't look very good yet. If you want to prevent long computations, using a low number for MaxRecursion like 0 or 1 is usually a good idea. PerformanceGoal -> "Speed" can also help.

Amplifying on Sjoerd's comment
$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  {Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi},
  Mesh -> All,
  MeshStyle -> Red,
  PlotPoints -> pts,
  MaxRecursion -> rec],
 {{pts, Automatic, "PlotPoints"}, {Automatic, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25},
  ControlType -> SetterBar},
 {{rec, Automatic, "MaxRecursion"}, {Automatic, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}},
 ControlType -> SetterBar]



I do not know how to force plot function linePlot, ParametricPlot e.t.c. to distribute plot points evenly along the curve. But you may roll your own.
To get approx. evenly distributed points along the curve, we may:

get x values evenly distributed points: xls.

get the lengths of the distance between xls[[i]] and xls[[i+1]]: len

determine the minimum length: min

If the distance between 2 points is larger than min, insert a new point.

plot the points and color the original points red.
myPlot[f_, npts_ : 10] := Module[{xys, len, min, pts}, Print[npts];
xys = {#, f[#]} & /@ Range[0, Pi, Pi/npts] // N;
len = {(#[[1, 1]] + #[[2, 1]])/2, (Norm[#[1] - #[[2]]])} & /@
Partition[xys, 2, 1];
min = Min[Norm /@ (Subtract @@ # & /@ Partition[xys, 2, 1])];
pts = Flatten[
MapThread[
If[#1[[2]] > min, {#2, {#1[1], f[#1[1]]}}, {#2}] &, {len,
Most@xys}], 1];
AppendTo[pts, xys[[-1]]];
ListLinePlot[pts, Mesh -> All, Epilog -> {Red, Point[xys]}]]


Here is an example with Sin:
myPlot[Sin, 10]


You may improve this by choosing more points to start with and by e.g. using Interpolation with order >1.
N.B. The formatting of code on this page does not work. That is way the code is oddly formatted.
